# Inverted circumflex in BibTex

Tags: bibtex, accents

To encode an inverted circumflex accent in text method I use the following formulation:

```
 \v{C}
```

Which produces the desired outcome:

[image]

In my BibTex file I have an author whose name requires the same accent:

```
Author = {Maksimovi\'{c}, \v{C}.},
```

This however, produces the following in the Bibliography section:

[image]

How should I encode the inverted circumflex in the BibTex file?

Comment: It should be `Maksimovi{\'c}, {\v{C}}.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accent is called *caron* (or *háček*).

The correct input for accented letters in BibTeX files is like

```
Maksimovi{\'c}, {\v{C}}.
```

Indeed, the test file

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{maks,
  author={Maksimovi{\'c}, {\v{C}}.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2017,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Citation: \cite{maks}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]